# No UUID for partition when partitioning a new disk

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, fstab, uuid

I am working on partitioning a new disk, on which nothing is stored yet, so I also need a completely new partition table, etc. To try doing this, I first made a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table and then assigned all of the space that was listed under the output of `print free` in `parted /dev/sda`.

I made this an [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) partition, with as much space as I could. After exiting `parted` again, I tried checking the partition's UUID, using `blkid /dev/sda*`, which results in:

```
/dev/sda: PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="ext4" PARTUUID="d8415694-74bb-457b-b028-d488ca6d64f2"
```

As you can see, no UUID for the whole drive is listed, only a PARTUUID is listed. As far as I know, in `/etc/fstab` when mounting the drive by uuid, I would need to have a device UUID to mount.

The output of `parted -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2879GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      17,4kB  2879GB  2879GB               ext4
```

And the output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2879.0 GB, 2878970265600 bytes, 5622988800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: C6A4181C-CEFD-4457-ACEF-577084496DD0


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1           34   5622988766    2,6T  Microsoft basic ext4
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I have tried adding either of these two lines to `/etc/fstab`, but both of them returned the error "`mount: can't find UUID=(...)`":

```
UUID=d8415694-74bb-457b-b028-d488ca6d64f2 /local                  ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=C6A4181C-CEFD-4457-ACEF-577084496DD0 /local                  ext4    defaults        1 2
```

What can I do to correctly mount this new disk under `/local`?

Comment: You need the UUID of the file system, not of the partition. Did you run `mkfs` to create a file system?

Comment: The partition UUID would also work, but of course it needs to be tagged `PARTUUID=`.

Comment: @grawity I also tried that, but it gave me a completely different error which I'm not sure what it is anymore. I think the solutions to create a filesystem on the partitions was the most important fix.

Comment: A definition: *[What is UUID, PARTUUID and PTUUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete the partition.
2. Recreate it so it starts at sector 1024 (this will fix `Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary`).
3. Give the partition hex code `8300` or (equivalently) `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4` GUID, so it's "Linux filesystem" (for now you have "Microsoft basic", this is wrong). In `gdisk` this can be done with `t`.
4. Run `mkfs.ext4` on the partition and create a filesystem. This is crucial.
5. Invoke `blkid` and find out the right `UUID` (not `PARTUUID`).
6. Use this UUID in your `fstab` (`UUID=…`, like you already tried with these other IDs).

Comment: Weird to see that the default partition code when creating it on linux is "Microsoft basic"... Anyway, this worked to both fix the warning of the physical boundary and the lack of UUID. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Why is file system creation required if PARTUUID is [a partition-table-level UUID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid/463410#463410) (not a file system-level UUID)? - *"it is accessible* ***without making any assumptions*** *at all about the* ***actual contents*** *of the partition"* (my emphasis)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because the OP wants to `mount` something via `/etc/fstab`. If there is no filesystem then there is nothing to mount.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a file system with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` which will create a unique `UUID` for you. Partitioning alone is not enough. Yes, the partition type is ext4, but without a file system...

And if this harddisk should be your only harddisk in the computer, you may want to create an [ESP (EFI system partition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) as your first partition to boot from. It's easier to partition your harddisk using `gdisk` in this case as you use the GPT partitioning scheme.

And if you want to do a fresh Linux install anyway, it might be easier to do the partitioning with the installation DVD.

Comment: This disk is actually a hard disk that's added aside from the SSD from which the OS runs, so that isn't a problem for me.

Comment: Then you only need to create a filesystem, find out the UUID and add an entry to your fstab.

Comment: Ehm, and change the partition type with gdisk as [Kamil](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski) pointed out. I thought it was already correct...

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem when I partitioned the disk using the SCSI path:

```
disk=lun3
printf "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" |fdisk /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/${disk}
```

I was not able to retrieve the UUID:

```
blkid /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/${disk}-part1
```

When I did the partitioning again (after removing the old partition) using the path `/dev/sdf`, I was able to see the UUID.

Comment: What was different? The alignment?